# Minimax algorithm efficiency

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I'm programming Tic-Tac-Toe using minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning after taking Harvard's CS-50. My logic is working perfectly, except for the return time of minimax (especially on the first call, when only one player played). I was thinking of replacing the extra recursive call of minimax to max/min value. I want to emphasize that minimax is taking relatively slow for my purposes (around 0.5 seconds) and that I can't use pre-computed data.

```
import math
import copy
import time

X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = None


def initial_state():
    """
    Returns starting state of the board.
    """
    return [[EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY],
            [EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY]]


def player(board):
    """
    Returns player who has the next turn on a board.
    """
    if board == initial_state():
        return X
    X_counter = 0
    O_counter = 0
    for row in board:
        for cell in row:
            if cell == X:
                X_counter += 1
            elif cell == O:
                O_counter += 1
    return O if X_counter > O_counter else X


def actions(board):
    """
    Returns set of all possible actions (i, j) available on the board.
    """
    possible_moves = set()

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[i][j] is None:
                possible_moves.add((i, j))
    return possible_moves


def result(board, action):
    """
    Returns the board that results from making move (i, j) on the board.
    """
    newboard = copy.deepcopy(board)
    newboard[action[0]][action[1]] = player(board)
    return newboard


def winner(board):
    """
    Returns the winner of the game, if there is one.
    """

    if board[0][0] == board[0][1] == board[0][2] != None:  # 1, 2, 3
        return board[0][0]

    if board[1][0] == board[1][1] == board[1][2] != None:  # 4, 5, 6
        return board[1][0]

    if board[2][0] == board[2][1] == board[2][2] != None:  # 7, 8, 9
        return board[2][0]

    if board[0][0] == board[1][0] == board[2][0] != None:  # 1, 4, 7
        return board[0][0]

    if board[0][1] == board[1][1] == board[2][1] != None:  # 2, 5, 8
        return board[0][1]

    if board[0][2] == board[1][2] == board[2][2] != None:  # 3, 6, 9
        return board[0][2]

    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] != None:  # 1, 4, 7
        return board[0][0]

    if board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] != None:  # 3, 5, 7
        return board[0][2]

    return None


def terminal(board):
    """
    Returns True if game is over, False otherwise.
    """
    def check_draw(board):
        for row in board:
            for cell in row:
                if cell is None:
                    return False
        return True

    if winner(board) is not None or check_draw(board):  # or someone won , or there is a draw
        return True
    return False


def utility(board):
    """
    Returns 1 if X has won the game, -1 if O has won, 0 otherwise.
    """
    temp = winner(board)
    if temp == X:
        return 1
    elif temp == O:
        return -1
    return 0


def minimax(board):
    """
    Returns the optimal action for the current player on the board.
    """
    options = actions(board)
    if player(board) == X:
        vT = -math.inf
        move = set()
        for action in options:
            v, count = minvalue(result(board,action), -math.inf, math.inf, 0)
            if v > vT:
                vT = v
                move = action
    else:
        vT = math.inf
        move = set()
        for action in options:
            v, count = maxvalue(result(board,action), -math.inf, math.inf, 0)
            if v < vT:
                vT = v
                move = action
    return move

def maxvalue(board,alpha,beta,count):
    """
    Calculates the max value of a given board recursively together with minvalue
    """

    if terminal(board): return utility(board), count+1

    v = -math.inf
    posactions = actions(board)

    for action in posactions:
        vret, count = minvalue(result(board, action),alpha,beta,count)
        v = max(v, vret)
        alpha = max(alpha, v)
        if alpha > beta:
            break
    return v, count+1

def minvalue(board,alpha,beta,count):
    """
    Calculates the min value of a given board recursively together with maxvalue
    """

    if terminal(board): return utility(board), count+1

    v = math.inf
    posactions = actions(board)

    for action in posactions:
        vret, count = maxvalue(result(board, action),alpha,beta,count)
        v = min(v, vret)
        beta = min(v, beta)
        if alpha > beta:
            break
    return v, count + 1
```